# PHP move_uploaded_file getting errors and file is not being uploaded

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a form and with input type file....what I am trying to do is save that file to the server (in this case, localhost)

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "/admin-uploads/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
```

and this is the error I get:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(/admin-uploads/home.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Site/admin/Insert.php on line 30

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpsoF2wg' to '/admin-uploads/home.jpg' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Site/admin/Insert.php on line 30
```

Am I missing code?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "/admin-uploads/" directory is a subdirectory of where this script is run. You need the full path to the destination directory.

as:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], __DIR__."/admin-uploads/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
```

fyi: please be aware that the 'user supplied' [image][name] may not be a valid filename. it may be worthwhile 'sanitizing' it.